# Drag & drop across frames with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, drag-and-drop

I would like to do this:

- Drag a DIV element from a first document that contains an IFRAME
- Drop this DIV element into into a second document, inside the IFRAME.

Is there a way to use jQuery UI draggable & droppable to achieve this? or otherwise do this in a cross-browser way, possibly with another JS library?

Comment: Functionality for this will be available in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/comms.html (see: Cross-document messaging)   There are examples of using javascript and canvas (http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/browser-ball/) but, you'll be limiting users if you enforce HTML5 support before HTML5 is standardized.

Comment: @JimSchubert Why would two different iframes of the same web application be different domains?

Comment: @NoBugs I'm not 100% sure, but I seem to recall there being security limitations if your iframes are loading assets from different domains. I've seen hacks of using localStorage to overcome security limitations of iframes, but haven't implemented anything like that myself. I tend to avoid iframes.

Comment: @JimSchubert Absolutely other sites shouldn't see others' content, or localstorage. It's easy to access iframe window and document from js if it's same-origin though.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by accessing the contents inside the iframe with jQuery this way:

```
$( 'your-iframe' ).contents().find( 'elements-to-find' ).droppable();
```

To make sure the iframe contents are loaded when you run the script, you must wait for the jQuery load event of the iframe.

```
$('your-iframe').load(function() {

    $( 'your-iframe' ).contents().find( 'elements-to-find' ).droppable();

});
```

I had the same necessity of you and managed to do drag and drop between iframes this way, and everything worked correctly.