# JavaScript/jQuery drag and drop element between two iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a page with 2 iframes, side by side, both from the same domain. I want to drag'n'drop an element from a specific drag-zone (e.g. a table) of one iframe to a specific dropzone (e.g. a list) on the other. I checked all related questions on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I can't find an appropriate solution. I tried it with jQuery UI draggable, but the problem is that the returned draggable element is contained within the iframe. I cannot drag it out of the iframe boundaries. So, my next thought was to create the draggable element on top (parent) window, but then I guess I'd have to somehow trigger a drag event on the parent window from the dragstart event on the iframe. But then, how would I detect the drop event when I mouse over the appropriate elements on the drop-frame?

Oh, and if that's not hard enough already, I'd like to make it work on IE8 too :)
But for now, let's just say that I will find a fallback solution for IE8 that will not involve drag'n'drop.

Comment: Attack the problem in two steps. First, figure out how to drag an item from inside an iframe into the parent document. Once you're there, getting from parent document to iframe is already solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075696/drag-drop-across-frames-with-jquery-ui/6814333#6814333

Comment: Can the draggable element be sticky (click to pick up, click again to drop), or does it have to work with the user holding the mouse/touch down?

Comment: It has to work like usual drag'n'drop, i.e. hold the mouse down to drag. Otherwise I know how to simulate the behaviour already.

Comment: @KevinB if you know the answer please enlighten us and claim the bounty. Yoda-like answers are not very helpful :)

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets Please show your HTML for both frames and the parent page.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets I don't have a complete answer (and i doubt very many people will.) Instead, i gave you enough direction to accomplish it on your own.

Comment: -1 for not showing any code or HTML. Show the HTML for both frames and the parent page, and I will reconsider. Basically: the problem is that if you `mousedown` in `frame1` then `mouseenter` will not trigger in `frame2` (while you are holding the mouse down) so you need to use something like `mousemove` to detect when you have crossed the frame border by checking `event.clientX, event.clientY` and comparing to the dimensions of the frame. With no code, seems like you are just farming your hard work out to SO users.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Seriously?! "-1 for not showing any code or HTML"?! I am "farming my hard work out to SO users"?! First of all, how hard is it to imagine the HTML for a simple page with 2 iframes side by side? Second, I didn't even ask for code. I asked for a solution, a simple description of the steps or a link to a related article would suffice. And no, KevinB's solution doesn't cut it because his 2 steps are breaking the dragging operation. I now realize that some people are here only to raise their reputation, but please, if you don't know the answer spare us the time.

Comment: Reread my comment. Using your logic you should be able to *imagine* the solution based on those tips. Also, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Learn it. Know it. Live it. The essence of the solution is that you need to 1) detect when you cross the frame boundary while dragging, and 2) remove the element from the source frame and add it to the target frame. You can keep track of the element being dragged in the parent page. What you are attempting is a challenging problem that jQuery is not good at solving. I would normally charge USD$2K or more for a solution like this.

Comment: And if I may add: don't be rude to people that are trying to help you. I am asking for clarification so that we CAN help you. Showing your markup will help us know whether the content of the iframes should be scrollable, for example, which has a huge impact on the solution. You need to give us more context for your problem domain. Even a screenshot would help.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary See, now, if you had written that last part with the steps from the beginning, I would've explained to you why it won't work in my case and it would've saved us some misunderstanding :) Which, I have to admit, supports your point that I should've included some code, or provided more details about the fact, for example, that there is a space between the frames, so you can't just remove the element from the source frame and add it to the target frame, you'd have to add it to the parent frame in between, and all this transparently to the user.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary So, I apologize for not being *that* clear, but judging from the answers I received, it is indeed a hard problem to solve and our users will just have to live with the solution I already implemented, which bypasses drag'n'drop altogether for a solution similar to what you suggested in the beginning, click to pick up, click to drop.
It's also nice to know that you'd charge someone $2K for this, I will tell it to my boss :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simulate dragging by sending mouse messages from the iframes to the parent, and doing the drag in the parent.  Here is a codepen showing dragging list items from one frame to another: http://codepen.io/brenzy/details/zxMZmO/

Since SO wants some code, here is the dragHandler talking to the parent:

```
$("li").mousedown(function (event) {
  dragElement = $(this);
  if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
  if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  event.cancelBubble=true;
  event.returnValue=false;
  return false;
});

$(document).mousemove(function (event) {
  if (dragElement) {
    if (!dragStarted) {
      // tell the parent to start dragging the item
      parent.postMessage({
        action: "dragStart", frame: myId,
        itemText: dragElement.text(), itemId: dragElement.attr('id'),
        offset: {left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY}
      }, '*');
      dragStarted = true;
    } else {
      parent.postMessage({action: "dragMove", frame: myId,
        offset: {left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY}}, '*');
    }
  }
});

$(document).mouseup(function (event) {
  if (dragStarted) {
    parent.postMessage({
      action: "cancelDrag", frame: myId,
      itemText: dragElement.text(), itemId: dragElement.attr('id'),
      offset: {left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY}
    }, '*');
  }
  dragStarted = false;
  dragElement = null;
});
```

NOTE:  This only works in Chrome, but I am pretty sure that you can get it working in other browsers.

Comment: Interesting, so you're not using native HTML 5 DnD support, and no drag events at all? I'll have to look into the code more closely, but your answer seems to be the best so far. Tell you what, if nobody else comes up with something better, you can have the bounty, at least for all the effort! (which, by the way, some people here would charge USD$2K for! :))

Comment: You mentioned that you wanted this to work in IE8.  I think that with a few small changes (setCapure for the mouse, and attachEvent for the messages) you should be able to get this working in IE8 as well.  I tried to see if I could come up with a solution to your problem, just because of those two comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not writing out the full code for you, because there is a lot of code involved in that. But I will give you the basics. It is called a message element. You can pass a message element to the parent window in the frame with a table. Then you would pass another message element from parent window to the child window with the list.

Unfortunately, the only spots I have in production with that going on is on websites that you have to be logged in to view. And my playground server is not viewable to the outside world. Otherwise I would show you a working example and let you steal the code from me, or at least get a good idea as to how it works.

See if you place the 2 sets of code listed below in 2 files if you can get it to work together,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                var iframeWin = document.getElementById("da-iframe").contentWindow,
                form = document.getElementById("the-form"),
                myMessage = document.getElementById("my-message");
                myMessage.select();
                form.onsubmit = function () {
                    iframeWin.postMessage(myMessage.value, "http://localhost/payground/");
                    return false;
                };
            };
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="the-form" action="/">
                    <input type="text" id="my-message" value="Your message">
                    <input type="submit" value="postMessage">
                </form>

                <iframe id="da-iframe" src="frame.php"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next bit should go in same directory named frame.php

```
<html><head>
    <script>
        function displayMessage (evt) {
            var message;
            if (evt.origin !== "http://localhost") {
                message = "You are not worthy "+evt.origin;
            }
            else {
                message = "I got " + evt.data + " from " + evt.origin;
            }   
            document.getElementById("received-message").innerHTML = message;
        }

        if (window.addEventListener) {
            // For standards-compliant web browsers
            window.addEventListener("message", displayMessage, false);
        }
        else {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", displayMessage);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="received-message">I heard nothing yet</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope that is enough that you can figure out the details as to what you want to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but no, that is not enough, and I don't even see the relevance to my question. We're talking about typical drag'n'drop user interaction, not communication between iframes. You're not even using mousedown/move/up events in your example. Maybe I have to be more precise in my question?

Comment: Yeah but it's the code used, you would have to change the code to have mouse drag. This example shows how to send data from different webpages in frames. Like I said this would give you the idea. If you actually want me to program it for you, you'd have to put out some cash.